# Computing $f^{*}\mathscr{O}_X$ directly via colimit

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I want to prove that, for affine schemes $X = \text{Spec} (A)$, $Y = \text{Spec} (B)$ and $f: Y \rightarrow X$ morphism of schemes ($\varphi: A \rightarrow B$), $f^{*}\mathscr{O}_X \cong \mathscr{O}_Y$ as locally ringed spaces over $Y$ and, then, as schemes.

Of course, it's possible to use the fact that $\mathscr{O}_X$ and $\mathscr{O}_Y$ are quasi-coherent and, then, conclude that $f^{*} \mathscr{O}_X \cong \mathscr{O}_Y$ as $\mathscr{O}_Y$-modules. However this isomorphism will be an isomorphism of $\mathscr{O}_Y$-algebras and, therefore, an isomorphism of locally ringed spaces. **(I noticed that this "proof" is possibly wrong, because $f^{*}$ for locally ringed spaces may not coincide with $f^{*}$ for $\mathscr{O}_Y$-modules)**

However **I want to prove this fact via the definition of $f^{*} \mathscr{O}_X$ as the sheaffication of $f^{-1}\mathscr{O}_X (U) = \varinjlim\limits_{f(U) \subset V} \mathscr{O}_X (V)$  and without using the adjunction $f^{*} \dashv f_{*}$**.

For the proof, it's sufficient to consider principal open sets $D (b)$ for $b \in B$. In this case, $f^{*} (D (b)) = \varinjlim\limits_{f(D(b)) \subset D(a)} A_a$. The condition $f(D(b)) \subset D(a)$ is equivalent to $D(a) \subset D(\varphi(b))$. If $b$ is in the image of $\varphi$ apparently there will be a cofinal $D(a)$, namely $D (\varphi^{-1} (b))$ for some choice in the inverse image. For the general $b$, i have no idea how to proceed. And, then, I'm stuck at this point. Any hint, idea or help would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't we missing a tensor product somewhere? Your $f^*$ seems to be defined like $f^{-1}$.

Comment: $f^*\mathcal{G} := \mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y} f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$ and $f^{-1}\mathcal{G} := \varinjlim\limits_{f(U) \subset V} \mathcal{G} (V)$ where $\mathcal{G}$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_Y$ modules.

Comment: @Krish: I think your $X$ and $Y$ are swapped, compared to the OP's.

Comment: @tracing: yeah. sorry. *In the above comment, the map is $f: X \to Y$*

Comment: In addition to the tensor product, it's missing a sheafification.

Comment: Sorry for not responding the comments, I was out of internet.  @Hoot I'm using the geometric morphism just in the the category of locally ringed spaces and not as modules, this is why there is no tensor product.

Comment: @user40276 I guess I don't know what that means :(

Comment: @Hoot I mean as the left adjoint of geometric morph isms of toposes. It's defined as your $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of $f^* \mathcal{O}_X$ (in bold-face) is not correct. This is $(f^{-1})_{pre}\, \mathcal{O}_X$. The difference to $f^* \mathcal{O}_X$ is that you first take the associated sheaf $f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_X$ of this presheaf and then tensor it along $f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_Y$. Notice that this implies *directly* $f^* \mathcal{O}_X \cong \mathcal{O}_Y$, just using the general nonsense fact $R \otimes_R S \cong S$ for (internal) ring maps $R \to S$. I think that $(f^{-1})_{pre}\, \mathcal{O}_X$ is usually not a sheaf, and even less an $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module.

Comment: Well, I think I you misunderstood me (but it's my fault, since my "pseudo-proof" is wrong). I mean $f^{*}$ as locally ringed spaces and not as modules (i.e., the geometric morphisms of toposes of locally ringed spaces). In this case, of course, you need to sheaffy $f^{-1} \mathscr{O}_X$. But, maybe I misunderstood you and you are saying that $f^{*}$ for locally ringed spaces coincides with the $f^{*}$ for modules...

Comment: I've edited my question. Hope you can understand now. Thanks for the response.

Comment: What is $f^*$ "as locally ringed spaces"? And you still want to prove $f^* \mathcal{O}_X \cong \mathcal{O}_Y$? But $\mathcal{O}_X$ is not a locally ringed space. Your question still does not make sense for me.

Comment: $f^{*} \mathscr{O}_X$ as the sheaffication of $f^{-1}\mathscr{O}_X (U) = \varinjlim\limits_{f(U) \subset V} \mathscr{O}_X (V)$ is  what I mean by $f^{*}$ as locally ringed spaces. For,  the definition of $f^*$ as modules, you will need to tensor with $f^{*} \mathscr{O}_X \rightarrow \mathscr{O}_Y$.

Comment: I think my notation is not the standard one, since what I mean by $f^{*}$ as locally ringed spaces you're calling $f^{-1}$

Comment: By geometric morphism I mean the usual definition for toposes (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+morphism). In the case of locally ringed spaces, $\text{Ring} (Y) \xrightarrow{f^{*}} \text{Ring} (X)$. In the case of modules $\mathscr{O}_Y -\text{Mod} \xrightarrow{f^{*}} \mathscr{O}_X-\text{Mod}$